# Excel VBA code to automate

Tags: excel, vba

I have recorded the following VBA macro in Excel

```
Sub EnterDate()
'
' EnterDate Macro

' Enter date at any point in a worksheet and move cursor down

'

' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+x

'
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "12/15/2014"

    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

What I need to be able to do is to be able to insert different years, months, and days, and loop back to repeat the process in the cells below. The above code only inserts the defined date. I would like to enter month, hit [ENTER], enter day, hit [ENTER], enter year hit [ENTER], display the date and move down to the next cell, repeating the loop until stopping execution.

Comment: `ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select` in nonsensical. Starting from the active cell, you move down one row and then select cell `A1`? Did you mean `Range("A1").Offset(1,0)` instead?

Comment: Why can't you just type the dates you want into Excel? Is there a sequence here or anything repeating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of curiosity, why would you use Ctrl+x (built in hotkey for "Cut" command) to hotkey this macro procedure?

Simple `Do ... Loop` with a messageBox to prompt you to continue (or quit) and InputBox to capture the values you want to put on the sheet.

```
Sub EnterDate()
'
' EnterDate Macro

' Enter date at any point in a worksheet and move cursor down

'

' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+x

Dim mb as VbMsgBoxResult
Dim y as String, m as String, d as String

Do 

    y = Application.InputBox("Year?")
    m = Application.InputBox("Month?")
    d = Application.InputBox("Day?")

    ActiveCell.Value = m & "/" & d & "/" & y
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

    mb = MsgBox("Continue?", vbYesNo)
Loop While Not mb = vbNo

End Sub
```

Comment: Many thanks, David. I am just trying to learn VB, weaning myself away from Lotus123 which I love only because of its simplicity to write macros. This is my first simple exercise. In Lotus123, a macro named \x with the code "@date({?},{?},{?})~{down}{branch \x}" does the job perfectly. In Excel, using VB, it ain't so simple. Your code works beautifully, except that selecting "No" for "Continue?" does not stop execution. Not a big deal, but I love your approach. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Try now, I forgot to set the `mb` variable to the message box result :)

Comment: Works smoother than a baby's bottom! I'm now really getting interested in learning more VB - I used to program in Basic many, many years ago. I greatly appreciate help from folks like you.